# css card flip animation flip and then content flickers to visible

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a card flip animation on my website, the card shows and image and a title, and when you hover on the card it flips to show the content, the content should be visible straight away but there is a flicker where the content cannot be viewed until the flip animation has finished, can anyone tell me why, I am totally stumped.

Here is my CSS and HTML structure.

```css
.flip__card {
  margin-bottom: $multiple;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  perspective: 1000px;
  min-height: 256px;
  @include breakpoint(tablet-l) {
    margin-bottom: $lg-multiple;
  }
  img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: $multiple / 2;
    display: block;
    @include breakpoint(tablet-l) {
      margin-bottom: $lg-multiple / 2;
    }
  }
}

.flip__card--inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 256px;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip__card__label {
  min-height: $multiple * 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  @include breakpoint(tablet-l) {
    min-height: $lg-multiple * 2;
  }
}

.flip__card__front,
.flip__card__back {
  padding: $multiple / 2;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-right: 1px solid $light-grey;
  border-bottom: 1px solid $light-grey;
}

.flip__card__front {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: $white;
}

.flip__card__back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background-color: $light-grey;
  border-color: $grey;
  .member__bio {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: $multiple * 9;
    p {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    @include breakpoint(tablet-l) {
      height: $lg-multiple * 9;
      p {
        margin-bottom: 0;
      }
    }
  }
}

.flip__card:hover .flip__card--inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flip__card">
  <div class="flip__card--inner">
    <div class="flip__card__front">
      <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" data-src="{{member.photo.one().getUrl('teamPhoto')}}" alt="{{member.title}}" class="blackAndWhite" />
      <div class="flip__card__label">
        <h4 class="alt noMargin"><span class="script">{{member.title}}</span></h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flip__card__back">
      <div class="member__bio">
        {{member.bio|widont}} {% if member.linkAuthor is defined and member.linkAuthor|length %} {% include '_partials/common/button' with { 'label':'Title', 'weight':'secondary', 'url':'url' }%} {% endif %}
      </div>
      <!-- bio -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here you can see what this creates,

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/87Development/pen/YzXYqbq)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about. I tried to slow down the transition to 2 seconds and it seems ok to me. Which browser are you using?

Comment: It's an old behavior, the solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172954/css-not-rendering-backface-the-first-time-around-on-3d-transform) always worked for me even though it's quite hacky.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried something similar to this and I found a much easier way to do this if you want you can try this way this uses maybe this might help for making the thing you want to do easier

[try this out!](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_flip_card.asp)